# How to load multiple external .svg file into one <svg> tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm new to the SVG world.

Currently, I know that I can insert an .svg file into a web page using the `<object>` tag, or draw something from scratch using the `<svg>` tag and javascript.

However, for some reason, I would like to create some drawing on-the-fly using javascript code AND import into it some static external files.

I don't know how to do it.

If possible, I want to be able to position imported files relative to some elements of the "host" svg (the one created on-the-fly).

I prefer tips using native javascript, but tricks using one of the classic svg libs are welcome too. In fact, I haven't made any choice regarding which svg lib to use for instance ;)

Any idea?

Comment: BTW if there is something weird with this question, why not explaining it to me, rather than downvote me with no reason. I said I'm new to SVG, and would be happy to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to change the external SVG, use SVG's [`<image>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag), which works similar to the HTML `<img>`:

```
<image xlink:href="other.svg" x="0" y="0" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

If you want to change the external SVG content, use nested [`<svg>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg). This allows you to position the other SVG inside your SVG, while retaining the external SVG's coordinates etc.

```
<svg>
  <svg x="100" y="100" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="width: 300; height: 300">
    <!-- content of the external SVG file in here -->
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How do you load an external SVG file into a svg tag?

Comment: Just by using a standard Ajax request, get the response as text or XML and put it in.